# Javadoc - How to add general comments about a class?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

How can I generate general comments in Javadoc to better describe a class's usage?

I want to add a section similar to the area that begins with "Linked list implementation of the List interface..." in the  LinkedList class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) above the Field Summary.

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html  Very short and incomplete answer: you use `/** ... */` type of comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a javadoc above your class..

```
/**
 * Doubly-linked list implementation of the {@code List} and {@code Deque}
 * interfaces.  Implements all optional list operations, and permits all
 * elements (including {@code null}).
 *
 * ...
 * <p>This class is a member of the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/../technotes/guides/collections/index.html">
 * Java Collections Framework</a>.
 *
 * @author  Josh Bloch
 * @see     List
 * @see     ArrayList
 * @since 1.2
 * @param <E> the type of elements held in this collection
 */
public class LinkedList<E>
    extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
    implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
 // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, I thought there existed a separate tag for this section.